# BS4 gathering rows to list

Tags: python, excel, beautifulsoup

could anyone please help a beginner out. I have written some code that gathers all the company names for a website. It also prints out all of them. However, when I try to enter the data into an excel file, it only enters the last company name.

Heres the code: If anyone could help I'll appreciate it a ton.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import Workbook



print('Welcome!')
search = input('Search for what? ')

URL = 'https://www.merinfo.se/search?ap=1&emp=0%3A100&rev=0%3A100000&d=c&who=' + search + '&where=&bf=1'
headers = {
    'User Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Safari/605.1.15'
}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')





for i in soup.find_all('h2', class_='name'):
    print(i.get_text())




workbook = Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active

sheet["A2"] = i.get_text()
workbook.save(filename="foretagen.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sheet.append()` to add rows to excel file.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import Workbook


print('Welcome!')
search = input('Search for what? ')

URL = 'https://www.merinfo.se/search?ap=1&emp=0%3A100&rev=0%3A100000&d=c&who=' + search + '&where=&bf=1'
headers = {'User Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Safari/605.1.15'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

workbook = Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active

for i in soup.find_all('h2', class_='name'):
    txt = i.get_text(strip=True)
    print(txt)
    sheet.append([txt])

workbook.save(filename="foretagen.xlsx")
```

Prints:

```
Welcome!
Search for what? tree
Tree Logistics AB
Sushi tree AB
Beech Tree AB
BIN TREE AB
TALENT TREE AB
Juniper Tree AB
Hope Tree AB
Dead tree group AB
The Tree Karsikko AB
Willow Tree Consulting AB
Learning Tree International Aktiebolag
Palm Tree Tunes AB
Tree of Pets AB
nordic tree care AB
For Tree i Rossön Aktiebolag
Trädkompaniet Voice Of Tree Care AB
Omsorgshuset Red Tree Care Center AB
Global Tree Care i Sundbyberg AB
Three Rock AB
Three Gates AB
```

and writes excel file (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]